# Appending items to a list using jQuery but use index if items are the same using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Kind of a nebulus subject I know.

I have a "cart" build in Javascript.  My example is on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4v6wb2ys/4/).

In my example, there is a list of input boxes on the left column in the HTML output controlled by a '+' and '-' buttons.
The values increase and decrease accordingly.
In the right column the values are limited by what get's inputted on the left. This is the 'Product'
At the bottom of the output you will see the "Cart".
I am appending items to the "Cart" based off of the 'Product' selections.

I would like that IF the 'Product' items are similar, then I just need to output the index or the amount, like a cart would.  So in my instance, if there are 2 of the same product in the cart, put the amount of 2 next the list item.

```
 var increment;
 var $InputValue = $('.ProductDetailPage').find("input[data-attendee='" + gaData + "']");
 $InputValue.each(function (index) {
     var oldThisVal = $(this).attr("value");
     var newThisVal = oldThisVal;
     var newBoxValInc = parseFloat(oldThisVal) + 1;
     var newBoxValDec = parseFloat(oldThisVal) + 1;
     var parentSection = $(this).parents("section").attr("id"),
         productname = $(this).parents("section").find('h2').text(),
         $list = $(this).parents("section").find(".CartList ul"),
         //[data-attendee='" + gaData + "']
         attendee = $(this).data("attendee"),
         attendeeprice = $(this).data("attendeeprice"),

         li = '<li class="animated bounceIn ' + attendee + parentSection + ' item' + $(this).val() + '"><span class="itemName">' + productname + '</span><span class="attendeeType"> ' + attendee + '</span><span class="itemPrice"> $' + attendeeprice + '</span></li>';

     if ($button.text() == "+") {
         increment = true;
     } else {
         increment = false;
     }


     if ($(this).val() > 0 && increment == true) {
         $list.append(li);
         var listItemsCount = li.length;
     } else {
         $list.find("li." + attendee + parentSection).last().remove();
     }
```

**EDIT: ADDED EXPLANATION OF DESIRED OUTPUT**
So my right now the code above only appends items to a list like so:

```
Adult Ticket
Junior Ticket
Junior Ticket
Junior Ticket
```

My desired effect would be:

```
1 - Adult Ticket
3 - Junior Ticket
```

I am asking this question because I don't know where to start based on what I already have. I am appending to the list, BUT I don't know how to just add the item once, then if there are more than one of the same items to just increment a number before the list item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And so what exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: @PatrickQ, Instead of having my list items just keep appending to the list, that IF the items are the of the same item, then append and increment the total number of items to the beginning of a list item.  Right now the list is just appending to the list, but if there are items of the same type, they just add. So in my example if there are more than 2 junior tickets in the list, it just appends the tickets to the list. I want to just append one list item, then if there are more than one append a total to the one list item. Does that make sense?

Comment: Added edit of desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT NOW EVERYTHING WORK**
DEMO: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4v6wb2ys/9/)
I have got some problems with `listItemsCount` (and I don't understand the utility).
However, considering the string `attendee + parentSection` unique, I have added a `data-qta` `attribute` to the `li` (initially equal to `1`).
 When you click the button the script check if the class already exists, if false it retrieve the data-qta and some stuff(check qta, remove if zero, update qta and numbers), otherwise it adds a new `li`

```
var sectionClass=$button.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('ProductDetailPage'),
    element = $list.children('li.' + attendee + parentSection),
    qta = parseInt(element.attr('data-qta')),
    relatedInput=$('.ProductDetailPage').find('input[data-attendee="' + attendee+'"]');

    if(sectionClass==false ){
        qta = parseInt(relatedInput.val());
        if(qta>newVal){
            relatedInput.val(newVal);
            qta=newVal+1;
            sectionClass=true;
        }
    }

    if(sectionClass){
         if($list.children('li.' + attendee + parentSection).length > 0) {

            ($button.text() == "+")? qta++:qta--; 
            if (qta > 0) {
                element.attr('data-qta', qta);
                element.children('.itemPrice').html(attendeeprice + ' x ' + qta);
            } else {
                element.remove();
            }
         } else {
             var li = '<li class="animated bounceIn ' + attendee + parentSection + ' item' + $(this).val() + '" data-qta="1"><span class="itemName">' + productname + '</span><span class="attendeeType"> ' + attendee + '</span><span class="itemPrice"> $' + attendeeprice + '</span></li>';
             $list.append(li);
         }
         calculateCart();
    }
```

Comment: Good sir. That is EXACTLY what I needed. The help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: actually that is extremely close.  It is not decrementing properly.  Seems that the count is a bit off.  If a user chooses an Adult ticket and 2 Junior tickets the incrementing actually shows 3 not 2 for the Junior. And it does not remove the item completely if the value hits zero.

Comment: It may be the way I was testing it.  If you decrement and then increment the value of the Juniors from 2 to 0 then back up to  2 it seems to be keeping the value of 1 then incrementing again up to 2 the count for the Junior is goes up to 3.  And THANK YOU so much for the help.

Comment: @ClosDesign I have solved the remove problem, however the other one is due to the fact that there is no distintion between the two column button, for js the are the same, in fact the same thing happens foryour fiddle if you try. May I add something to distinguish them?

Comment: @ClosDesign Test ypur fiddle: add some tickets, then press the minus button of the left column, you will remove the li, but if you press +, then ou will laso add the tickets

Comment: @ClosDesign now **EVERYTHING** works: add, remove, quantity, Guests Attendees minor than Film Attendees, total...**EVERYTHING**